# How to find Difference of two datetime fields in mysql in a specific format

Tags: mysql

I have a table having two fields start_date and end_date. I need to display the data in this format

```
4 days 12 hours remaining.

id      start_date           end_date
1       2012-12-07 12:00:00  2012-12-14 12:00:00
```

How can i achieve this. Using now() of mysql to find remaing days and hours. I mean today is 2012-12-10 so i need to find how much difference from today to the end date.

Comment: i said i need to find differnece from now to the end date but the solutions are producing difference from start date and end date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you:

```
SELECT
    FLOOR(HOUR(t) / 24) AS days,
    HOUR(t) % 24 hours
FROM (
    SELECT TIMEDIFF('2012-12-07 12:00:00', '2012-12-14 18:00:00') t
) AS t1
```

In the nested query you get the difference (in hours)

Comment: Wonder full mate...:-)
+1 for your thinking

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this helps ::
Try `TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF())`

```
select 
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_date, start_date))/86400 as days,
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_date, start_date))/3600- TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_date, start_date))/86400 as hours
from
myTable
```

Comment: @raheelshan: You can look and go with  Teneff's answer, it looks very good, and it is giving the desired result...